# How do I use filter with an Apps Script array and fetch only the row with specific user ID in the cell?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have an Apps Script which fetches data from four different columns but it fetches all the rows. I'd like it to only push the row that matches the user ID which is a randomly generated 8 digit number.

```
function doGet(req) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var output = [];
  for(var i = 1; i<values.length; i++) {

    var row = {};
    row['User'] = values[i][0];
    row['Name'] = values[i][1];
    row['Email'] = values[i][2];
    row['Phone'] = values[i][3];
    row['Notes'] = values[i][4];
    

    output.push(row);


  }

return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({data: output})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON); 

}
```

[The result](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbzgutFEciOCaMboaMsXyl8M9ae5Pw3J_q9oWwTUrxeamN5t6yJWLA6IUnQhGIRu_8c3/exec)

I've tried specifying the cell range like "A1:B1" but it doesnt work.
Tried to specify the 8 digit user ID in the getValues() but no luck.

Comment: To assist you in getting the answer that you're looking for, it's best if the community has a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), such as a dummy sheet, that can be used for replication. This would allow us to understand what you'd like to accomplish and provide targeted solutions. It doesn't need to be the exact data that you have if it's sensitive information. This is just so we can visualize and replicate what you have.

Comment: Hi, I've added the exact result I get from running the above code. I have just 6 rows of data and all of them are showing. I need to change the script to only fetch a specific row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try starting with something like this:

```
function myfunk(id) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var [User,Name,Email,Phone,Notes] = sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow() - 1,5).getValues().filter(r => r[0]==id)[0];

}
```

Answer (score 2):

### SUGGESTED SOLUTION

I recommend adding a condition that would check the user IDs that you have which would be something like this:

```
if (row['User'] == "87654321") {
  output.push(row);
}
```

The completed code would become:

```
function doGet(req) {
  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var values = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var output = [];
  for (var i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = {};
    row['User'] = values[i][0];
    row['Name'] = values[i][1];
    row['Email'] = values[i][2];
    row['Phone'] = values[i][3];
    row['Notes'] = values[i][4];
    if (row['User'] == "87654321") { // Put the ID of the user here
      output.push(row);
    }
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({ data: output })).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}
```

### OUTPUT

[image]

### REFERENCE

- [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions, and I'll be happy to help in any way I can!

Comment: I LOVEE this! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, good sir!